# Use Task.Run instead of Delegate.BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have recently upgraded my projects to ASP.NET 4.5 and I have been waiting a long time to use 4.5's asynchronous capabilities. After reading the documentation I'm not sure whether I can improve my code at all.

I want to execute a task asynchronously and then forget about it. The way that I'm currently doing this is by creating delegates and then using `BeginInvoke`.

Here's one of the filters in my project with creates an audit in our database every time a user accesses a resource that must be audited:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
    var id = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

    var invoker = new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        var audit = new Audit
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            IPAddress = request.UserHostAddress,
            UserId = id,
            Resource = request.RawUrl,
            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

        var database = (new NinjectBinder()).Kernel.Get<IDatabaseWorker>();
        database.Audits.InsertOrUpdate(audit);
        database.Save();
    });

    invoker.BeginInvoke(StopAsynchronousMethod, invoker);

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

But in order to finish this asynchronous task, I need to always define a callback, which looks like this:

```
public void StopAsynchronousMethod(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var state = (MethodInvoker)result.AsyncState;
    try
    {
        state.EndInvoke(result);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var username = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
        Debugging.DispatchExceptionEmail(e, username);
    }
}
```

I would rather not use the callback at all due to the fact that I do not need a result from the task that I am invoking asynchronously.

How can I improve this code with `Task.Run()` (or `async` and `await`)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understood your requirements correctly, you want to kick off a task and then forget about it. When the task completes, and if an exception occurred, you want to log it.

I'd use `Task.Run` to create a task, followed by `ContinueWith` to attach a *continuation task*. This continuation task will log any exception that was thrown from the parent task. Also, use `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` to make sure the continuation only runs *if* an exception occurred.

```
Task.Run(() => {
    var audit = new Audit
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            IPAddress = request.UserHostAddress,
            UserId = id,
            Resource = request.RawUrl,
            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

    var database = (new NinjectBinder()).Kernel.Get<IDatabaseWorker>();
    database.Audits.InsertOrUpdate(audit);
    database.Save();

}).ContinueWith(task => {
    task.Exception.Handle(ex => {
        var username = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
        Debugging.DispatchExceptionEmail(ex, username);
    });

}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

As a side-note, background tasks and fire-and-forget scenarios in ASP.NET are *highly* discouraged. See [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response; it's exactly what I was looking for. I will definitely go over all of my asynchronous code and determine whether it is necessary for it to execute as a background task.

Answer (score 11):

It may sound a bit out of scope, but if you just want to forget after you launch it, why not using directly `ThreadPool`?

Something like:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            x =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Do something
                        ...
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // Log something
                        ...
                    }
                });
```

I had to do some performance benchmarking for different async call methods and I found that (not surprisingly) `ThreadPool` works much better, but also that, actually, `BeginInvoke` is not that bad (I am on .NET 4.5). That's what I found out with the code at the end of the post. I did not find something like this online, so I took the time to check it myself. Each call is not exactly equal, but it is more or less functionally equivalent in terms of what it does:

1. `ThreadPool`: 70.80ms
2. `Task`: 90.88ms
3. `BeginInvoke`: 121.88ms
4. `Thread`: 4657.52ms

   ```
   public class Program
   {
       public delegate void ThisDoesSomething();

       // Perform a very simple operation to see the overhead of
       // different async calls types.
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           const int repetitions = 25;
           const int calls = 1000;
           var results = new List<Tuple<string, double>>();

           Console.WriteLine(
               "{0} parallel calls, {1} repetitions for better statistics\n", 
               calls, 
               repetitions);

           // Threads
           Console.Write("Running Threads");
           results.Add(new Tuple<string, double>("Threads", RunOnThreads(repetitions, calls)));
           Console.WriteLine();

           // BeginInvoke
           Console.Write("Running BeginInvoke");
           results.Add(new Tuple<string, double>("BeginInvoke", RunOnBeginInvoke(repetitions, calls)));
           Console.WriteLine();

           // Tasks
           Console.Write("Running Tasks");
           results.Add(new Tuple<string, double>("Tasks", RunOnTasks(repetitions, calls)));
           Console.WriteLine();

           // Thread Pool
           Console.Write("Running Thread pool");
           results.Add(new Tuple<string, double>("ThreadPool", RunOnThreadPool(repetitions, calls)));
           Console.WriteLine();
           Console.WriteLine();

           // Show results
           results = results.OrderBy(rs => rs.Item2).ToList();
           foreach (var result in results)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(
                   "{0}: Done in {1}ms avg", 
                   result.Item1,
                   (result.Item2 / repetitions).ToString("0.00"));
           }

           Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
           Console.ReadKey();
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// The do stuff.
       /// </summary>
       public static void DoStuff()
       {
           Console.Write("*");
       }

       public static double RunOnThreads(int repetitions, int calls)
       {
           var totalMs = 0.0;
           for (var j = 0; j < repetitions; j++)
           {
               Console.Write(".");
               var toProcess = calls;
               var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
               var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
               var threadList = new List<Thread>();
               for (var i = 0; i < calls; i++)
               {
                   threadList.Add(new Thread(() =>
                   {
                       // Do something
                       DoStuff();

                       // Safely decrement the counter
                       if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref toProcess) == 0)
                       {
                           resetEvent.Set();
                       }
                   }));
               }

               stopwatch.Start();
               foreach (var thread in threadList)
               {
                   thread.Start();
               }

               resetEvent.WaitOne();
               stopwatch.Stop();
               totalMs += stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
           }

           return totalMs;
       }

       public static double RunOnThreadPool(int repetitions, int calls)
       {
           var totalMs = 0.0;
           for (var j = 0; j < repetitions; j++)
           {
               Console.Write(".");
               var toProcess = calls;
               var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
               var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
               var list = new List<int>();
               for (var i = 0; i < calls; i++)
               {
                   list.Add(i);
               }

               stopwatch.Start();
               for (var i = 0; i < calls; i++)
               {
                   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                       x =>
                       {
                           // Do something
                           DoStuff();

                           // Safely decrement the counter
                           if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref toProcess) == 0)
                           {
                               resetEvent.Set();
                           }
                       },
                       list[i]);
               }

               resetEvent.WaitOne();
               stopwatch.Stop();
               totalMs += stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
           }

           return totalMs;
       }

       public static double RunOnBeginInvoke(int repetitions, int calls)
       {
           var totalMs = 0.0;
           for (var j = 0; j < repetitions; j++)
           {
               Console.Write(".");
               var beginInvokeStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
               var delegateList = new List<ThisDoesSomething>();
               var resultsList = new List<IAsyncResult>();
               for (var i = 0; i < calls; i++)
               {
                   delegateList.Add(DoStuff);
               }

               beginInvokeStopwatch.Start();
               foreach (var delegateToCall in delegateList)
               {
                   resultsList.Add(delegateToCall.BeginInvoke(null, null));
               }

               // We lose a bit of accuracy, but if the loop is big enough,
               // it should not really matter
               while (resultsList.Any(rs => !rs.IsCompleted))
               {
                   Thread.Sleep(10);
               }

               beginInvokeStopwatch.Stop();
               totalMs += beginInvokeStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
           }

           return totalMs;
       }

       public static double RunOnTasks(int repetitions, int calls)
       {
           var totalMs = 0.0;
           for (var j = 0; j < repetitions; j++)
           {
               Console.Write(".");
               var resultsList = new List<Task>();
               var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
               stopwatch.Start();
               for (var i = 0; i < calls; i++)
               {
                   resultsList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(DoStuff));
               }

               // We lose a bit of accuracy, but if the loop is big enough,
               // it should not really matter
               while (resultsList.Any(task => !task.IsCompleted))
               {
                   Thread.Sleep(10);
               }

               stopwatch.Stop();
               totalMs += stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
           }

           return totalMs;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

> Here's one of the filters in my project with creates an audit in our database every time a user accesses a resource that must be audited

Auditing is certainly *not* something I would call "fire and forget". Remember, on ASP.NET, ["fire and forget" means "I don't care whether this code actually executes or not"](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/). So, if your desired semantics are that audits may occasionally be missing, then (and only then) you can use fire and forget for your audits.

If you want to ensure your audits are all correct, then either wait for the audit save to complete before sending the response, or queue the audit information to reliable storage (e.g., Azure queue or MSMQ) and have an independent backend (e.g., Azure worker role or Win32 service) process the audits in that queue.

But if you want to live dangerously (accepting that occasionally audits may be missing), you can mitigate the problems by registering the work with the ASP.NET runtime. Using the [`BackgroundTaskManager` from my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html):

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
  var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
  var id = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

  BackgroundTaskManager.Run(() =>
  {
    try
    {
      var audit = new Audit
      {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        IPAddress = request.UserHostAddress,
        UserId = id,
        Resource = request.RawUrl,
        Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
      };

      var database = (new NinjectBinder()).Kernel.Get<IDatabaseWorker>();
      database.Audits.InsertOrUpdate(audit);
      database.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      var username = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
      Debugging.DispatchExceptionEmail(e, username);
    }
  });

  base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```